# Want to create Object Class with draw methode from an image resource ask in a View of an Android application

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception, drawable, getresource

I want to create Object Class with draw methode from an image resource ask in a View of an Android application.
I have 3 java files :

Balle.java :

```
package com.example.balle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
 
public class Balle extends Activity {
   float radius = 75;      // Radius of the Bubble
   float x = radius + 20;  // Center of the Bubble (x,y)
   float y = radius + 40;
   Context context = BalleView.GlobalContext;
   Resources res = context.getResources();
 
   // Constructor
   public Balle() {
 
   }
 
   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
       // show objet from the image
       Bitmap monImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.bubble);
       canvas.drawBitmap(monImage, x-radius, y-radius, null);
   }
}
```

BalleView.java :

```
package com.example.balle;
 
import com.example.balle.Balle;
 
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.View;
 
public class BalleView extends View {
   private Balle ball;
   public static Context GlobalContext = null;
 
   // Constructor
   public BalleView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      ball = new Balle();
   }
 
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      // draw the bubble
 
       // show objet from the image
      ball.draw(canvas);
   }
 
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.balle;
 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      View BalleView = new BalleView(this);
      setContentView(BalleView);
      BalleView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
   }
}
```

As my image resource in res/drawable :
[bubble.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV3Sn.png)

I have a null pointer error message on console :

```
08-09 04:05:14.791: D/AndroidRuntime(1232): Shutting down VM
08-09 04:05:14.791: W/dalvikvm(1232): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a81ba8)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): Process: com.example.balle, PID: 1232
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.balle/com.example.balle.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.example.balle.Balle.<init>(Balle.java:15)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.example.balle.BalleView.<init>(BalleView.java:16)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at com.example.balle.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
08-09 04:05:14.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1232):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks for help.

I had used the debugger and i think that the code and resources are corrects but it had somes associated files / folders of my IDE Eclipse that are not correctly configured. I had 2 warnings :

Error : BaseDexClassLoader.class > Class File Editor > Source not found

Error : ActivityThread;performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) > Source not found > Edit Source Lookup Path...

I had a "Android.jar" file but I don't know how to join source to my project in Eclipse.

Thanks for help

P.S. : The ultimate target is to move the bubble image on the screen.

Comment: **Any ideas ?**

Comment: I had installed the "Java Source Attacher" from the marketplace of Eclipse but in right clic of the android.jar and android-support-v4.jar to attache source, i had an error message : Library Source Location > sorry but source code cannot be found in our database. You can help the community by providing URL location of source code archive below.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger cannot be launch with breakpoint on a class.
The file "Android.jar" has to be linked with android sdk folder "sources".

Finaly, i add "import com.example.balle.BalleView" in MainActivity.java.
And the file Balle.java is not necessary with this BalleView.java :

```
package com.example.balle;
 
import com.example.balle.Balle;
 
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;
 
public class BalleView extends View {
   public static Context GlobalContext = null;
   private Paint paint;
 
   // Constructor
   public BalleView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      paint = new Paint();
   }
 
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 
       // show objet from the image
 
       Bitmap monImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bubble);
           canvas.drawBitmap(monImage, 40, 40, paint);
   }
 
}
```